# What is the proper use of the "federalism" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

[This question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/871/how-was-the-us-able-to-create-a-federal-department-of-education) was originally tagged with the [federalism](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/federalism) tag.  However, it was subsequently removed.  This question deals directly with the distinction between state and federal power and the answer hinges upon the interaction of Article I and the 10th Amendment.  I also feel that people interested in the topic of this question are likely looking for information as part of a broader federalism debate and is most likely to be found that way.

What was inappropriate about this tag on this question?

Answer (score 2):

I added that tag precisely because the root of that question was whether this was a federal or state power.  I don't know why it was removed, but I agree - it shouldn't have been!

Answer (score 0):

I removed the [federalism](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/federalism) tag because the question was not about the ***subject*** of federalism. The principles of federalism are only *obliquely* related to the crux of the question itself. Tags are not supposed to be a listing of  keywords mentioned in the question. It's supposed to describe what the question itself is about.

I could just as easily (incorrectly) tag that question [powers], [congress], [tradition], [money], [funding], or [supreme-court]… but that question is not *about* those subjects, so **that would be incorrect.**

Removing that tag was the correct action for this question.